# remove extra dot before \ref{} in latex

Tags: xetex, longtable, xtable

When I cross-reference a `longtable` (with label `x.big`) using `\ref{x.big}`, I get `.tablenumber` rather than `tablenumber`. How to get rid of the dot? Many thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[11pt,authoryear,1p,times,sort&compress]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\RaggedRight}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
A cross-reference to table~\ref{tab:xbig}.

\begin{longtable}{|l|P{4cm}|P{6cm}|*{5}{c|}}

%% header and footer information  
\caption{Papers used for bibliometric analysis}
\label{tab:xbig}\\ 
\hline
& 1st Author, Year, Journal & Title & LCS & TCS & TCS/t & LCS/t & AAC \\ 
\hline
\endfirsthead
\hline
\endlastfoot

%% body of table
1 & Fall Fs, 2020, Rev Dev Econ & Adoption and Use of Mobile Banking by Low-Income Individuals in Senegal & 0 & 0 & 0.00 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
2 & Motta V, 2020, Int J Hosp Manag & Lending Technologies and Access to Finance for SMEs in the Hospitality Industry & 0 & 2 & 2.00 & 0.00 & 2.00 \\  
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please tell us which document class you employ and how `table` environments are numbered in main.tex.

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,authoryear,1p,times,sort&compress]{elsarticle}, tables are number using Rstudio, so I am saving this xtable from R directly with x.big.tex and I am trying to ref {} it in latex

Comment: With the information you provided so far, the issue you describe is not reproducible. If I use the documentclass and the table code your provided in the question and add `\ref{x.big}` to forma a small example document, I get just the table number without any additional dot. You will however have to do some alterations to your table code. First of all, there is a `\\ ` missing right before the last `\hline`. Also, your table is a lot wider than the textwidth.

Comment: the problem is in code you have not shown. The caption is at the top of the table so you can remove all but one line of the table from the example, as it is not relevant to your question, but do add a _complete_ small document that sets up the incorrect numbering.

Comment: Naming table file as `x.big.tex` is not smart idea. Dot in file name can confuse Latex. Instead  it use some other symboil, for example `-` or `_` or simple remove it.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of radically simplifying your code, to focus on what's relevant. (E.g., it suffices to show rows of input, rather than 100 rows, of the `longtable` environment.) As it stands, your now greatly simplified code does *not* generate the problem behavior you wish to fix. So the cause of the problem must lie elsewhere in the code. Please advise.

Comment: I have the same problem with the `elsarticle` document class. Would somebody maybe be so kind as to provide an answer?